# MUP Deploy failures on a project that works on another server

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment

I'm trying to deploy with meteor to a server configured pretty much the same as one that is working fine.  I've been going around and around this with the help of MasterJames on the git issues tracker for mup but were not getting anywhere so here I am.

My mup.json is

```
    {
 19   // Server authentication info
 18
 17   "servers": [
 16     {
 15       "host": "10.1.23.2",
 14       "username": "root",
 13       // "password": ""
 12       // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
 11       "pem": "/var/root/.ssh/id_dsa"
 10     }
  9   ],
  8
  7   // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  6   "setupMongo": false,
  5
  4   // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  3   "setupNode": true,
  2
  1   // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  0   "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",
  1
  2   // Install PhantomJS in the server
  3   "setupPhantom": true,
  4
  5   // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server.
  6   // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  7   "enableUploadProgressBar": true,
  8
  9   // Application name (No spaces)
 10   "appName": "thedash",
 11
 12   // Location of app (local directory)
 13   "app": "/Users/me/Documents/src/meteor/theboard",
 14
 15   // Configure environment
 16   "env": {
 18     "ROOT_URL": "https://thedash.there.com",
 19     "PORT": 3080,
 20     "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://localhost:27017/indata/"
 21   },
 22
 23   // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
 24   // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
 25   "deployCheckWaitTime": 150
 26 }
```

with url's changed to protect the guilty.

My Settings.json is

```
     {
  0   "public": {
  1
  2   }
  3 }
```

When I run sudo mup deploy (after sudo mup setup has run successfully) I'm getting errors, but there different pretty much each time.  Initially it was not able to find node-gyp which I installed manually, but now some of the errors are..

```
    [10.1.23.2] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
gz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-4.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.5.2.tgz
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
 > ./bcrypt: npm install due to binary npm modules
bindings@1.0.0 node_modules/bindings

nodeunit@0.9.1 node_modules/nodeunit
└── tap@0.7.1 (inherits@2.0.1, buffer-equal@0.0.1, slide@1.1.6, deep-equal@1.0.1, yamlish@0.0.7, nopt@3.0.4, mkdirp@0.5.1, difflet@0.2.6, runforcover@0.0.2, glob@4.5.3)
make: Entering directory `/opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory `/opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
[10.1.23.2] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
h failed https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support/-/source-map-support-0.2.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-4.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
 > ./bcrypt: npm install due to binary npm modules
bindings@1.0.0 node_modules/bindings

nodeunit@0.9.1 node_modules/nodeunit
└── tap@0.7.1 (inherits@2.0.1, buffer-equal@0.0.1, slide@1.1.6, deep-equal@1.0.1, yamlish@0.0.7, nopt@3.0.4, difflet@0.2.6, mkdirp@0.5.1, runforcover@0.0.2, glob@4.5.3)
make: Entering directory `/opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory `/opt/bocorockdash/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on.

The server config is

```
    npm version
{ http_parser: '1.0',
node: '0.10.36',
v8: '3.14.5.9',
ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
uv: '0.10.30',
zlib: '1.2.8',
modules: '11',
openssl: '1.0.1l',
npm: '1.4.28' }

node --version v0.10.36

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
```

Any ideas where to go from here. This has worked on another server (all be it a while ago for the setup) faultlessly for months with another instance of the same code.

Comment: What version is your Meteor app? 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: It's still 1.1. I tried a 1.2 upgrade on another branch but ran into package errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  The issues turned out to be nothing to do with mup or meteor. The problem was that mysql running on the same box had a processor pegged for some reason. Restarting mysql to release the resources, upgrade to 1.2 (although I don't think that had anything to do with it) and the deploy worked.